# How Oracle "row_limiting_clause" for rowcount| percent PERCENT rows works in Oracle 12c?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, analytics, oracle12c

Platform: Windows 7 x-64
Database: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit.

How Oracle `row_limiting_clause` for  rowcount| percent PERCENT rows works in Oracle 12c ?

Oracle `row_limiting_clause` acts strangely.
In Below code,table "fetch_test" has 10 rows

Case 1
When use `row_limiting_clause` with fetch first 0.5 rows only I get,

```
no rows selected
```

Case 2
When use row_limiting_clause clause with first 5 percent rows only I get

```
1 row as output.
```

Case 3
When use row_limiting_clause clause with first 1 percent rows only I get

```
1 row as output.
```

This means Case 1!=Case 2 [0.5!=0.5 (5 percent of 10 rows)]

```
SQL> select * from fetch_test;

  COL1 COL2                                                                 
  ---- ----                                                           
     1 A                                                                    
     2 B                                                                    
     3 C                                                                    
     4 D                                                                    
     5 E                                                                    
     6 F                                                                    
     7 G                                                                    
     8 H                                                                    
     9 I                                                                    
    10 J                                                                    

10 rows selected.
```

case 1:

```
SQL> select col1 from fetch_test
  2  fetch first 0.5 rows only;

no rows selected
```

case 2:

```
SQL> select col1 from fetch_test
  2  fetch first 5 percent rows only;

  COL1                                                                      
  ----                                                                      
     1                                                                      

  1 row selected
```

case 3:

```
SQL> select col1 from fetch_test
2  fetch first 1 percent rows only;

COL1                                                                      
----                                                                      
   1  

 1 row selected
```

What Oracle Documentation has to say,

If row count includes a fraction, then the fractional portion is truncated. If 
row count is NULL, then 0 rows are returned
["source"](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55645)

This explain case 1,but i can not find possible explanation for case 2 and 3 in my above example. 
Any Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is rounding up to get the number of rows for a percentage, perhaps.  The documentation is quite clear that 0.5 is treated as 0, due to truncation.  So, the two cases are not at all the same thing.

Comment: Thanks.Nice Guess but i also thought that but it is not mentioned any where in documentation or article i found that,percent will get rounded off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation is correct.  A strict reading of the Oracle docs indicates that this behavior is correct:

- rowcount case specifies that fractions are truncated.
- no mention is made that percents are truncated.  Therefore, it is reasonable to assume that the percents aren't truncated.

This seems reasonable, since a fractional number of rows doesn't make logical sense, but a fractional percentage does make logical sense.

> Use rowcount to specify the number of rows to return. rowcount must be a number or an expression that evaluates to a numeric value. If you specify a negative number, then rowcount is treated as 0. If rowcount is greater than the number of rows available beginning at row offset + 1, then all available rows are returned. If rowcount includes a fraction, then the fractional portion is truncated. If rowcount is NULL, then 0 rows are returned.
>
> Use percent PERCENT to specify the percentage of the total number of selected rows to return. percent must be a number or an expression that evaluates to a numeric value. If you specify a negative number, then percent is treated as 0. If percent is NULL, then 0 rows are returned.

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm

And for this specific set of numbers, we can observe that Oracle rounds 5% of 10 to 1.

```
> select 10*.05, round(10*.05) from dual;
10*.05 round(10*.05) 
------ ------------- 
   0.5             1
```

update, rishabi notes:

> a remainder (when using PERCENT in the row limiter) will ALWAYS return a whole number rounded UP, as per http://community.oracle.com/message/13176927#13176927

Comment: It is an answer backed up by logical correct assumptions.but,I am waiting for votes and other answers to mark it as right answer.

Comment: sounds good!  in either case, I think oracle could clarify their documentation.

Comment: @MarkHarrison . . . Non-truncation of the percentage *value* does not explain why 5% of 10 rows = 1 row and not 0.  It might explain why 5.5 percent is treated as either 5 or 6 percent, though.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, good observation.  10*.05 will round to 1, and I've updated the answer accordingly.  Thanks!

Comment: @MarkHarrison.It does not round up the percent.Check my updated question.
for case 3,you will get

SQL> select round(10*0.01) from dual;

 ROUND(10*0.01)                                                       
--------------                                                       
        0

Comment: a remainder (when using PERCENT in the row limiter) will ALWAYS return a whole number rounded UP
https://community.oracle.com/message/13176927#13176927

Perhaps this should be added